# Why isn'y my KIOSK app is updating automatically?

Tags: android-management-api, android-managed-profile

I have a KIOSK app that runs on fully managed devices. I have pushed several updates on PlayStore and I can see the updated version on PlayStore App but they are not updating automatically.

I also set the `auto-update` policy to `Always` but still no luck. Help appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the [SystemUpdateType](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#systemupdatetype) set to WINDOWED to configure Play apps to be updated within a daily maintenance window. This is strongly recommended for kiosk devices because this is the only way apps persistently pinned to the foreground can be updated by Play.

And by default, apps are updated automatically when the following constraints are met:

- The device is connected to a Wi-Fi network.
- The device is charging.
- The device is idle (i.e. not actively used).
- The app to be updated is not running in the foreground.

Google Play typically checks for app updates once a day, so it can take up to 24 hours before an app update is added to the update queue. After an app is added to the queue, it will be automatically updated the next time the constraints above are met.

Comment: Thanks @Deyzel for your response, I will try that out and post my feedback :)

Comment: Good response. Just to add to that. In my case, when the app is in the foreground, I've had to turn off "Battery Optimization" for Google Play Store app for the update to work. I have a backdoor from my kiosk app to the settings app, so I either do it manually or with adb (still need a backdoor to enable adb)

Answer (score 1):

There is a property **"minimumVersionCode": integer,"** in the application policy. you need set it for your application.hope this will help.

Comment: where is this policy/property? I can't find it in the Android Management API.